# Attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from sys import argv

from os.path import exists

print "Look what I can do"

script,This_file,That_file,=argv

print "I'm gonna paste this into that"

Whatever=open(That_file)

Whatevers = That_file.read()

"So That_file is %d bytes long"%len(Whatever)

"Do the input and output files exist?"% exists(This_file,That_file)

Huh=open(That_file)

Huh.write(Whatever)

    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Okay I'm relatively new to this site so please excuse the unusual look of the question.I hope you all can still help me.I was just trying to create a program which pasted contents from one .txt to another.

Comment: You can't read a string, you can read a file. `That_file` is a string, `Whatever` is a file.  >> `Whatever.read()`

Comment: What is your question? White line causes the error? Why is your code double spaced? Please use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: My question was about why I got the attribute error with read ans it was on line 7.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. This site really is the best place for getting answers.And I am really sorry for the ugly question and I didn't know that spacing made such a big difference when being read by others.It won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

it's:

```
Whatever=open(That_file)
Whatevers = Whatever.read()
```